# Ridiculous slow Doctrine Query

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have already read some articles on Doctrine performance, but this one query is so slow it seems just wrong:

```
public function getBetRoundMainDataBuilder(BetRound $betRound){
        $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('br')
                   ->select('br, uG, u, b, gG, g, t1, t2')
                   ->where('br.id = :bID')
                   ->setParameter('bID', $betRound->getId())
                   ->innerJoin('br.userGroup', 'uG')
                   ->innerJoin('uG.users', 'u')
                   ->innerJoin('br.gameGroup', 'gG')
                   ->leftJoin('gG.games', 'g')
                   ->leftJoin('g.team1', 't1')
                   ->leftJoin('g.team2', 't2')
                   ->leftJoin('br.bets', 'b' );
        return $qb;

    }
```

I know it has a lot of Joins, but I thought I rather query everything within one query instead of lazy load all dependent Data.

I have profiled the code and although this query does not select too much data it takes endlessly for an array_shift:

[image: Profiling Data]

Am I missing something? I even changed the Hydration Mode to array, but still have problems.

**UPDATE:**
I have now tried to select only partially but didn't change too much:

```
           ->select('partial br.{id},
                     partial uG.{id},
                     partial u.{id, firstName, lastName, nickName, username, imageName},
                     partial b.{id, data},
                     partial gG.{id, title},
                     partial g.{id, data, date},
                     partial t1.{id, name, shortName, shortCode, logoName},
                     partial t2.{id, name, shortName, shortCode, logoName}')
```

Next step is to split the query up.

**Update 2**

It is getting better, I have several areas in my View where I need different Datasets. I tried to split my content up into those Areas and also Query accordingly:

*Data for Main Area:*

- BetRound

  - GamGroup (only to get the Games)

    - Games

      - Teams
      - Bets (only for Current User!)

This looks now like this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('br')
        ->select(
            'partial br.{id},
            partial b.{id, data},
            partial gG.{id, title},
            partial g.{id, data, date},
            partial t1.{id, name, shortName, shortCode, logoName},
            partial t2.{id, name, shortName, shortCode, logoName}'
        )
        ->where('br.id = :bID')
        ->setParameter('bID', $betRound->getId())
        ->innerJoin('br.gameGroup', 'gG')
        ->leftJoin('gG.games', 'g')
        ->leftJoin('g.team1', 't1')
        ->leftJoin('g.team2', 't2')
        ->leftJoin('g.bets', 'b', 'WITH', 'b.user = :user')
        ->setParameter('user', $user->getId());
    return $qb;
```

*Second Area is the PointTable*

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('br')
    ->select('br, b, u, uBs')
    ->where('br.id = :bID')
    ->setParameter('bID', $betRound->getId())
    ->leftJoin('br.bets', 'b')
    ->innerJoin('b.user', 'u')
    ->innerJoin('u.betroundStatus', 'uBs', 'WITH', 'uBs.betRound = :bID');

return $qb;
```

And then I have a third area which has all the stats. It is basically the same as the first Query but includes Bets for all Users. I am now unsure, If I should use only one query which queries all the Users Bets or, than for the stats create one query for each User or somehow different.

**UPDATE QUESTION:**

Maybe you see that I have a root entity called BetRound that kind of starts all queries (I am now up to 4 compley quersies from my BetRound?
I just don't know how I can "add" the data to my relations after initial load.
As you may see there are several join "paths" going from my BetRound. One of them is the "games path" that looks like:

- BetRound -> GameGroup -> Games -> Team1 & Team2
- BetRound -> UserGroup -> Users -> UserBetRoundStatus
- BetRound -> Bets

I need all this Data, but how do I get all the data in one root Entity with the correct relations? And If I query e.g. do I start with the e.g. GameGroup or always with my root entity(=BetRound)?

Comment: Well, you're selecting a lot of data. Try to select only the fields you need, not whole entities.

Comment: Also get the performed SQL and run EXPLAIN on it.

Comment: I have tried to change the selection only to the necessary fields, but then I get a ArrayResult with those fields in the main ResultArray, although the selected Data would be in a related entity.

Comment: You will want to decouple your query... 7 joins is overkill even more when hydrating. I generally aim for a max of 3 joins and in extreme cases 5 joins. In your case, it's probably more than 7 joins (because of potential manyToMany relationships).

Comment: But I do need all this data in one View. How would you solve this issue? I have already tried to reduce this whole thing to certain fields I need.

Comment: You could start by querying the join on "br.userGroup" and "br.gameGroup" individually (each query would filter by BetRound ID) and reiterate the effort from there. It won't change the fact that hydrating will still take a lot of time so I'd definitely use array instead of entities.

Comment: I can't really use Arrays, because I use some heavy aggregation logic in my Domain objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think there's a lot of left joins which may be really slow. You should rebuild this query and remove those left joins to improve some performance. Also please check if every keys and indexes are created properly in database.

In conclusion - it's not Doctrine's fault but the query.

Answer (score 1):

The actual query (`PDOStatement::execute()`) only takes 3% of the total. Seeing as interacting with a database *should be* the slowest part of a script, 3% of the total execution time is plenty fast.

The vast majority of the time is taken up by the following 3 method calls:

```
ArrayHydrator::hydrateRowData()   // 17%
AbstractHydrator::gatherRowData() // 39%
DateTimeType::convertToPHPValue() // 16%
```

If you count that up, it is 72% of the total. This is totally unacceptable by *any* standard.

- Is *"hydrating"* records really necessary?
- Can you eliminate the date/time conversion?

You just need to go after the biggest sinners. Shave off the fat.

Comment: Hi I temporarily played around with ArrayHydration and are now using object hydration again. But the result ist not really the absolute release.